# How to read two integer with a space in between, in php?

Tags: php, stdin

I am trying to read an integer which looks as following,

```
6
1
2 5
2 7
2 9
1
1
```

I want to read an integer which follows after number 2 which has space in between. But I am not able to read it. I have tried as follows.

```
$i = 0;
while($i<10){
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d", $arr[$i]);
    // I have tried fscanf(STDIN, "%d\t%d", $arr[$i]); this too.
    $i++;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Outputs as:

```
[0] => 6
[1] => 1
[2] => 2
[3] => 2
[4] => 2
[5] => 1
[6] => 1
```

But my expected output is:

```
[0] => 6
[1] => 1
[2] => 2
[3] => 5
[4] => 2
[5] => 7
[6] => 2
[7] => 9
[8] => 1
[9] => 1
```

I have also tried the following it's also not working.

```
while(fgets(STDIN)){
    echo $i++;
    echo "line: $f";
}
```

Comment: What are `$arr[$i]` options?

Comment: @PHPglue I am just saving input in that array.

Comment: Those are "The optional assigned values." according to the docs.

Comment: @PHPglue Yes it is, I hope the problem is with format in this case it's second paramater. According to docs fgets(STDIN) will read a line but it also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add two variable as you read two input

```
$handle = fopen('users.txt', "r");

$i = 0;
$result = array();
while($i<10){
    fscanf($handle, "%d\t%d",$arr[$i],$arr1[$i] );
    $counter = count($result);
    $result[$counter] =$arr[$i];
    if(!empty($arr1[$i])){
        $counter = count($result);
        $result[$counter] =$arr1[$i];
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

`users.txt` file contain

```
6
1
2 5
2 7
2 9
1
1
```

Comment: Thank you. I really had no idea I have to pass two variables to hold the values, Which is very common. Look at my answer If you are getting input at run time.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to get your input at running time.**

```
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
while($i<20){
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d\t%d",$arr[],$arr[]);
    $i++;
}
print_r(array_filter($arr));
```

Hope, this is useful for getting input value from runtime.

**And much cleaner way to skip white space in a above output is**

```
while($array = fscanf(STDIN, "%d\t%d")){
    //fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d",$arr[],$arr[]);
    //$i++;
    list($var1,$var2) = $array;
    echo $var1;
    echo $var2;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
6125272911
```